# file geodatabase and feature class visibility

Tags: python-2.7, arcgis

I've attempted to copy a raster of NLCD land cover from a folder to a file gdb and convert it to a feature class using *RasterToPolygon* from both ArcCatalog and ArcMap.  The command completes without error but it does not display in ArcCatalog.  If I repeat the same command I get the yellow triangle telling me that the *Output polygon feature* already exists and is confirmed by running ListFeatureClasses in Python (i.e., it shows the feature class). If I open ArcMap and attempt to Add Data, no feature class is shown.

I do not experience this if I copy it from one folder to another folder, only a file gdb.  Although if I try to run *feature class to feature class* with the newly created fc to the file gdb, it does not show.

I have created different file gdb's with the same result.
I updated my patches to what I'm told is current (running ArcGIS 10.2.2 on Windows 7).

Any thoughts on what's going on?

Thanks, Mike